# Which gems do I need to debug a Rails application in RubyMine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, rubymine

I use Ruby Mine 6.3, ruby 2.1 and Rails 4.0.3.
Which gems need to debug application with Ruby Mine, I tried use these gems:

```
  gem 'debugger'
  gem 'debugger-xml'
```

But application crashed with exit code 127 at breakpoint, and print this:

> .rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/debugger-1.6.6/ruby_debug.so:
>   undefined symbol: rb_vm_get_sourceline

**UPDATE**

I updated RubyMine to 6.3.1, dropped 'debugger', 'debugger-xml' (in Gemfile only 'ruby-debug-ide') and Debugging works!

Comment: Try debugger version 1.6.5 for Ruby 2.1.0.

Comment: I used 1.6.6 and I still have error

Comment: debugger2 should work? it has its own problems though, so I usually use debugger and fall back to debugger2 if needed.

Comment: Someone also mentioned elsewhere on SO something about RubyMine’s debugging system not working with debugger, so taking that out altogether makes debugging work... I have no idea why that would be like that, I don’t use RubyMine myself.

Comment: Did you update to rubymine 6.3.1? They fixed a lot of bugs. Also: on what platform are you (windows/mac/*nix)?

Answer (score 4):

I advise bunch of "better_errors" and "binding_of_caller".
You can read about this here: https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors

I'm usually use this gems:
https://gist.github.com/MrEmelianenko/11078561

Answer (score 2):

To enhance your console, use [pry-rails](https://github.com/rweng/pry-rails), better with `pry-doc`.

To debug in program, like using breakpoint, step in/over, you can use [pry-byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug) or [pry-debugger](https://github.com/nixme/pry-debugger).

p.s. this is my way to debug rails app in terminal, I'm not sure if it is ok with Ruby Mine. Hope this can help.

Answer (score 1):

I always liked `pry`. And its very useful with easy to learn [screencast](http://pryrepl.org/screencasts.html)
This is my debugging stack for my Ruby 2 & Rails 3/4 apps ;)

```
group :development do
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'pry-nav'
  gem 'pry-rescue'
  gem 'pry-stack_explorer'
  gem 'pry-doc'
end
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, you need ruby-debug-ide, but not debugger or debugger-xml.

For Rubymine/IDea + Ruby plugin with Ruby 2.0/2.1, also try the [debase](https://github.com/denofevil/debase) gem along with ruby-debug-ide to speed up debugging. Earlier versions had some trouble, but it works well, as of 2014-04-21.

Answer (score 0):

You already found your answer but I'd like to add small notes

Rubymine has an issue with the `debugger` gem, or probably it's the gems clashing(maybe), rubymine uses `fast-debugger (ruby-debug-ide)` and I think it doesn't like `debugger`, old versions suggested adding `debugger-xml` but from my trials that didn't really work so well, and current version kinda tolerates `debugger` a bit, but sometimes it freezes during breakpoints.

My teammates use `debugger`, so it's pushed to the repo, what I do is whenever I need to debug I just delete the `debugger` line from my `Gemfile` and wait for rubymine to detect that `Gemfile` change (about a second or two) and start my debugging session, I only put it back when I check the diff before pushing.